# IE6 "position: fixed" workaround doesn't work with select boxes when scrolling

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-6, css, scroll, multi-select

I am using the common CSS-workaround to achieve a fixed position of an element in IE6

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .fixedPos {
        position: fixed;
    }
</style>

<!-- IE specific code: -->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css"> 
    .fixedPos {  
        position: absolute;  
        top: expression(eval(document.compatMode && document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat') ? documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

My problem is that on pages that include scrolling and multi-select boxes the box rendering gets totally messed up when I start scrolling.

When I remove the `<iframe>` where the fixed element is, the scrolling works fine... (but then I have the famous `z-index` problem with the `<select>` elements).

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Here is an example HTML page I use for reproducing the error. When scrolling on this page the select box rendering goes haywire in IE6...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body class="">
    <style type="text/css">
        .fixedPos {
            position: fixed;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- IE specific code: -->
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fixedPos {
            position: absolute;
            top: expression(eval(document.compatMode && document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat') ? documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <iframe class="fixedPos" style="DISPLAY: block; width: 99%; height: 30px; z-index: 2" src="javascript:''" frameBorder="1" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <div width="99%" class="fixedPos" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; z-index: 3">
        <table width="100%" style="margin-bottom: 5px; background-color: yellow" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class=""> 1. Dum di dum </td>
                <td class=""> 2. Dum di dum </td>
                <td class=""> 3. Dum di dum </td>
                <td class=""> 4. Dum di dum </td>
                <td class=""> 5. Dum di dum </td>
                <td class=""> 6. Dum di dum </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div height="40px"></div>
    <br />
    <select id="" name="" size="14" multiple="multiple" style="width: 180px;" class="">
        <option value="value" selected="selected"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select id="" name="" size="14" multiple="multiple" style="width: 180px;" class="">
        <option value="value" selected="selected"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
        <option value="value"> My Value </option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the IE expression. Those are reevaluated with nearly every user interaction and are rather resource intensive. Maybe try positioning it with JS?